# Proving the polynomial identity $\,\, w[z,t]=\sum_{k=0}^{n}w_k(z)t^{n-1}.$

Tags: polynomials

I appreciate any suggestions you can give me to prove the next result:

Let $w_0(z)=1$ and for $k\geq 1$  $$w_k(z)=z^k+b_1z^{k-1}+b_2z^{k-2}+\cdots+b_k.$$

Let $w(z)=z^{n+1}+b_1z^n+\cdots+b_nz+b_{n+1}.$

If $\,\,\displaystyle w[z,t]=\frac{w[z]-w[t]}{z-t}\,\,$ show that $\,\,\displaystyle w[z,t]=\sum_{k=0}^{n}w_k(z)t^{n-1}.$

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of substituting the formula for $w_k(z)$ into the formula for $w(z,t)$, interchanging the order of summation, and recognizing $(z^n-t^n)/(z-t)$?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Lost interest??